# Superset Connect to a private database

Tags: apache-superset

I have a database running in a private VPC. The database isn't publicly accessible. Does superset support Connecting to databases via an SSH Tunnel? If so any link to the docs?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find it in the docs, but with the SSH tunnel you basically need to change the DB host to `127.0.0.1` (**not** `localhost`, since that's a keyword reserved for connection using the MySQL socket), and everything else should be the same.

For example, I tested with a MySQL database that I have running on `host.example.com`. I first created a tunnel redirecting my local port 3336 to MySQL's port 3306 (I did that because I already have MySQL running locally on 3306):

```sh
ssh -N -L 3336:127.0.0.1:3306 host.example.com
```

Then I was able to add it to Superset using this SQLAlchemy URI:

```
mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3336/dbname
```

Comment: What is the -N flag for? I don't get it in the usage list when running `$ssh`

Comment: On Mac OS: "-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports."

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`ssh -i /path/key-pair_instance1.pem username_of_instance1@i-0123456789abcdefa -L 9090:ec2-198-51-100-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306`

Here is the [source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ssh-vpc-resources/) with further explanation.